# Kurento group call not able to handle users without video?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

i implemented group calls in my website, and everything works nice, a few days ago i tested the system again but happend to join in a computer that had no webcam, only mic, and everyone else is not able to listen this user if he have no video. The test was:
User A- video and mic
User B- video and mic
User C- video and mic
User D- only mic

Everyone sees and listen everyone except User D that is not able to be listen from no body.

i tested with difrent computer, just unpluged the webcam and the bug is the same, if i have no video to share and join a grou call with a mic nobody can listen.

Im using last version of kms

Anyone knows if this a kurento Bug or something else?
I mean this type of situation should be fix by default, many people join group calls with no video and others with it, unless i am missing something that i need to add to cover that situations?
Thank you, sorry bad english.

Answer (score 0):

In the room, each client negotiates both audio and video. If you only provide audio, some navigators (like Chrome) can't handle the fact that you have negotiated both audio and video, but are only providing audio. Therefore, it waits until you provide a video track, so both tracks are synchronized.

The solution is to have clients negotiate the type of media they are going to provide, and not both.

Comment: so if i make the client setup the midea type only to audio, is that it? and in the request side ? imean the other people that go get this client stream?

I will check it out soon, thank you will post feedback

Comment: @LionL yeah, those would need that too. Does it happen in FF?

Comment: Question, by Media Type Audio, you mean passing video false audio true in constrains only?
I only use Chrome for now, only after i finish the platform i will make comtible stuff for other browsers, gona try now the stuff we talked, will post results soon, thank you.

Comment: I added to the user if he have no video to set constrains with video false, and when others request this user stream also to video false.

The server crashes,
If i remove the video false from the ones that request streams, it works fine exept the one that have no video that cant be listed from nobody.

Comment: Nevermind, it was me that screwd up in the ice candidates, its working like you sayd thank you